convert html to pdf using weasyprint dimension error
I created a function using weasyprint (I tried other libraries like xhtml2pdf, pdfkit but I always end up facing some problem and weasyprint was the one that came closest to achieving the objective.
I am converting the HTML to PDF and uploading it to cloudnary, I upload it as an "image" to be viewed via browser. The thing is that I am having a problem when converting dimensions, the HTML when converted to PDF is 1/4 of the correct size. I tried adding CSS classes, but it didn't work, can anyone give me a light on how I can maintain the original size of the HTML while converting?
template = session.query(EmailTemplate).filter(EmailTemplate.name == "Document Payment received").first()
pdf_path = f"proofpayment-{payment.payment_number}-{invoice.invoice_number}-{user.username}"
css = CSS(string='@page { size: A4; margin: 1cm; }')
HTML(string=html_message).write_pdf(pdf_path, stylesheets=[css])
# Upload para o Cloudinary {...}
 return proof_payment_url

The HTML is the size I want, but the PDF or the image are 1/4 of the correct size. I've included an image of how it looks.
Can anyone give me some guidance?
